# CONNECT BY PRIOR

Tags: sql, oracle

How to break out query on third nesting?

```
 SELECT CHILD_ID
   FROM COLLECTION_ITEMS 
  START WITH PARENT_ID = 16917 
CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID
```

I have such query and if nesting rise to more then three I must end query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LEVEL pseudocolumn.

```
SELECT
  CHILD_ID
FROM
  COLLECTION_ITEMS
WHERE
  LEVEL <= 3
  START WITH PARENT_ID      = 16917
  CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID
```